# Docker Stack tasks Rejected because of Permission denied error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-stack, docker-network

I tried to deploy a stack (contains one service) with `docker stack deploy` command and run 2 instance from my application on swarm! here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 1024M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks: 
      - server_network
networks: 
  server_network:
```

After running `sudo docker stack deploy -c ./docker-compose.yml ts` command, My stack successfully deployed to swarm, But here is my `docker stack ps ts`  output:

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                         NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR                              PORTS
8zmjp6wt47ki        ts_server.1         makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Ready               Rejected 2 seconds ago    "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
88vizpnabbi8         \_ ts_server.1     makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Shutdown            Rejected 7 seconds ago    "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
609hl7hy7tnu         \_ ts_server.1     makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Shutdown            Rejected 12 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
gif8fvbgdhpy         \_ ts_server.1     makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Shutdown            Rejected 17 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
x60x9c6albe5         \_ ts_server.1     makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Shutdown            Rejected 22 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
ugvbw1gpdp8e        ts_server.2         makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Ready               Rejected 2 seconds ago    "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
p34x1kp55ch8         \_ ts_server.2     makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Shutdown            Rejected 7 seconds ago    "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
3exxflukrl4y         \_ ts_server.2     makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Shutdown            Rejected 12 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
ud83xfj5nefj         \_ ts_server.2     makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Shutdown            Rejected 17 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"   
ws35na8up793         \_ ts_server.2     makbn/thumbnailer-server:v1   fanap9-lp           Shutdown            Rejected 22 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permis…"
```

And the full error message is **mkdir /var/lib/docker: permission denied**

And the other problem is when i tried to create stack with `docker service create` command services deployed and running successfully but i cant access to the service from my localhost! i have 2 questions:

1. what is the problem with deploy stack from compose file and why i get **mkdir /var/lib/docker: permission denied** error?
2. how to configure my service networke k to accessible from host?

Comment: Do you use a private registry?

Comment: @Alon no i use docker hub

Comment: I have exactly the same error on ubuntu 18.04. If you solved it please inform us

Comment: @dios231i could not solve this problem and changed my host os

Comment: I also have the same problem on my Ubuntu 18.04.. please who has solved it??????

Answer (score 11):

(Note: only relevant to users who may have installed docker via `snap`)

I experienced this issue because I had `snap` installed docker, which meant that docker-compose was confused about my docker installation. The `/var/lib/docker` was giving file permission errors because my system was actually using docker at `/snap/bin/docker`

To check whether this is the case for you, you can run `which docker`. If it returns `/usr/bin/docker`, you've done the normal app install. If it returns something at the path `/snap/` that means you've installed from the snap docker package (which is no longer maintained. Ref: https://github.com/docker/docker-snap)

To fix the issue, I first uninstalled the snap docker install using `snap remove docker` and then installed it through the `docker` setup instructions at https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#docker-ee-customers. Once I did that, I could deploy stacks without issue.

I can't remember where the idea came into my head to snap install docker instead, but installing by setting up repositories and then running `sudo apt install docker.io` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @dios231 please check this answer and let me know if solved your problem! I changed my os and can't confirm this answer right now

Comment: I took a similar approach, but for Docker CE, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x86_64. I noticed that the "type" command only indicated snap for docker-compose, but not for docker. I installed from a package instead of repository, described here: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package. I also changed version entry in docker-compose.yml to 3.7 before doing a new build. It then worked fine! docker-compose must be installed separately, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/install, and run sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/docker-compose afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

I was troubleshooting this issue for a few hours earlier where the containers would display as being rejected and shutdown due to the same Permission Denied error. I also had the same context of being able to manually create+scale a service but not being able to achieve the same results with my `.yml`.

Following the [getting started guide](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#your-first-docker-composeyml-file), in their `docker-compose.yml` example they use `version: "3"` but do not go on to say that's supposed to match your corresponding Compose File Format number. My number ended up being "3.7" based on the version of Docker I installed and after I changed it in `docker-compose.yml` accordingly my containers were able to replicate as intended via `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml some-name`.

**Compose File Format (CFF) : Docker Engine Release (DCR)**

```
CFF     DCR
3.7     18.06.0+
3.6     18.02.0+
3.5     17.12.0+
3.4     17.09.0+
3.3     17.06.0+
3.2     17.04.0+
3.1     1.13.1+
3.0     1.13.0+
2.4     17.12.0+
2.3     17.06.0+
2.2     1.13.0+
2.1     1.12.0+
2.0     1.10.0+
1.0     1.9.1.+
```

Reference doc available ([here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/))

**Example of Invalid to Valid Change**

```
# From the Example
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: username/repo:tag

# What's actually required (in my case, because I'm using docker version 18.09.2)
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: username/repo:tag
```

**Results After Change**

```
owner@test_server:~/myyml$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                               PORTS
baxip2g6xgzy        first-swarm_web     replicated          5/5                 [username]/getting-started:my-serv   *:4000->80/tcp

owner@test_server:~/myyml$ docker service ps first-swarm_web
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
ss6jn07htkhp        first-swarm_web.1   [username]/getting-started:my-serv   test_server         Running             Running 37 minutes ago                       
n5eael5ae3jl        first-swarm_web.2   [username]/getting-started:my-serv   test_server         Running             Running 37 minutes ago                       
kzb3l1hzdpet        first-swarm_web.3   [username]/getting-started:my-serv   test_server         Running             Running 37 minutes ago                       
6ijgoebvhhdg        first-swarm_web.4   [username]/getting-started:my-serv   test_server         Running             Running 37 minutes ago                       
h0mbz1fp1id6        first-swarm_web.5   [username]/getting-started:my-serv   test_server         Running             Running 37 minutes ago
```

Comment: even after changing version i am getting same error.